# The rocks refuse to split properly

Tags: godot

Basically, when the player collides with a rock, the rock should split into smaller rocks. Instead the rock creates a new rock that *is* smaller, but then becomes a bigger rock, why is it doing this?

```
func split():
    if scale.length() > 1:
        for i in range(1, 2):
            var offset = Vector2(cos(i * PI / 4), sin(i * PI / 4))
            var child = rock.instance()
            child.scale = scale/4
            child.position = position + offset * scale
            child.vel = vel + offset
            get_parent().add_child(child)
    get_parent().remove_child(self)
```

Full source [here](https://github.com/Parkpopking/Space-Derby/tree/master)

Edit: I found a solution. When I originally posted this I was using _ready() to set the properties of new rocks, I didn't realize that that function *isn't* called when creating a new instance, so when I created a child instance, these properties weren't set before I was changing them, but after when I added the children to the parent scene. So to fix it I simply changed _ready to _init and it solved the problem.

Comment: Please, make sure we have all the information we need in the body of your question. Nobody likes to have to go through several files to understand what (and where) your issue is.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind next time I have an issue

Comment: Well, `_ready` gets called when your instance enters the scene tree (that is on `add_child(x)`)

Answer (score 0):

Ranges are inclusive on the lower end and exclusive on the higher end.

So doing `for i in range(1, 2)` makes your loop have only one iteration.

Comment: That's wasn't the actual problem though, when the rock splits the child is smaller for an instant, but then blows up to the parent's size, making it impossible to ever reach the case where there won't be another child, and causing a visual bug. The range producing less then it should was a response to the screen becoming filled with rocks, which is caused by the bug I'm asking for help with (the refusal to shrink to a small enough size to be simply deleted on impact combined with all the new bodies that could be collided with on splitting leading to an overabundance of rocks.)

Comment: Well, in that case, maybe your initial rock is referenced by more than one parent? Have you tried calling `queue_fee()` on it instead of `get_parent().remove_child(self)`?